# AngularJS tabs, performance (Nodes & Heaps)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodes, heap-memory, ngtable

I'm developing my first AngularJS App. The App has various features but introducing one in particular I started having performance problems (Nodes and Heap). The section involved is composed of one or more tabs (max six). Each tab contains within it a table, the detail of an element of the table and an additional external filter.

The plugin used for table is ng-table. The number of columns in the table can be up to 20. The columns must be sortable, filterable, displayed or hidden and has to be possible to move to rearrange the display order. To do this I had to do a custom header (attached).

Find below a screenshot of the performance at the opening of six tabs simultaneously.

Is possible that the problem was made by the old version of ng_table plugin ? Because after upgrade it the performance is improving!

What can I do to improve? Please, help me.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/5YhCb]